# redesigning my database

Tags: mysql, database-design, versioning

On a old web app I had a table with the following structure:
`tools(id, name, abbreviation, width, height, power, type)`

The thing is that I need to add history support to the tools. The working scenario is that details of each tool can be modified, and I need to  keep track of the changes. For example, if I need to see the details of a tool from a certain date from the past, how can I do that?

How the database have to looks?

Comment: What have you thought of so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep the same table, but add a `dateEffective` field, and then create a new row every time a tool changes. Then when querying the table, you can get the version of a tool at a given date using:

```
SELECT * FROM tools WHERE id=@id AND dateEffective<@thisDate ORDER BY dateEffective DESC LIMIT (0,1)
```

**EDIT** You may wish to create another field called `toolVersionId` as a primary key.

**EDIT 2** In response to your comment, how about:

```
SELECT *
FROM tools t1
WHERE toolVersionId IN (SELECT toolVersionId
                        FROM tools t2
                        WHERE t2.id = t1.id
                        ORDER BY t2.dateEffective DESC
                        LIMIT (0,1)
                       );
```

Comment: do you have any idea about how can i get the entire table, with the last state only of the tools?

Comment: @doledoug I've posted my attempt at this, but not sure if it will work (I'm no expert, sorry!) Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

there are probably many ways to do this.  One way I have had success with in the past would be to add a `version_id` column to the table.  So the combination of `id` and `version_id` becomes the full key for any specific version of a tool.  Note that with this approach it is very easy to get all versions of a particular tool, you just select on the `id`.  Getting the current version of the tool is also easy, its just `id, max(version_id)`.

A downside of this approach is you need to write code to manage the versioning.

Comment: Perhaps some nifty triggers could "archive" the versions automatically?

Comment: @mike, yes that's certainly a possibility, although I didn't do it that way in the past.

Comment: Yea DB logic is kinda anti-mySQL..  I'm more of a Postgres guy and we don't mind writing DB code :)

Comment: @MikeChristensen: which is the difference between postgres and mysql from this point of view?

Comment: I don't have much mySQL experience, but to me the "cultures" seem different - Oracle, SQL Server and Postgres promotes more of a "let's get the database to do all our work" philosophy, while mySQL promotes a more "use the database only to store your data, and do your calculations in the middle tier" mindset.  This is a sweeping generalization, of course, but I think it holds some truth.

Answer (score 1):

Create a ToolsVersions table with all the same columns, only add a timestamp as well.  Every time you change tools, save the old values to the ToolsVersions table with the current timestamp.  Then, you can fairly easily query for all versions between a certain range, or find the version nearest to a desired date.